# How to link selenium server via docker compose

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose

How to link selenium server via docker compose to another container?
My docker-compose.yml is:

```
 version: '2'
    services:
        selenium:
            image: selenium/standalone-chrome
            ports:
                - "4444:4444"
        lamp:
            build: ./lamp
            ports:
                - "3306:3306"
                - "80:80"
            volumes:
                - /projects:/var/www/projects
            links:
                - selenium
```

then

```
sudo docker exec -it composelamp_lamp_1 /bin/bash
root@68a87ec3325f:/# curl http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 4444: Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is wrong. They are different containers, so the host is not localhost.

Try: `http://selenium:4444/wd/hub`

The service name is added as a hostname alias for the container

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment, so I write an answer:

Can you check if the port 4444 is already used by another application? Or may be just publish another port. Try for example something like:

```
ports:
    - "19900:4444"
```

and then try to connect to `http://127.0.0.1:19900/wd/hub`

I hope it helps.

edit : it can also be, that your application is not running on your localhost (127.0.0.1). In that case you should figure out on what IP address it's running.

Comment: I tryed:
        selenium:
            image: selenium/standalone-chrome
            ports:
                - "19900:4444".
Then on the host machine http://127.0.0.1:19900/wd/hub works fine, but on the lamp container:
    root@c7e314041b14:/# netstat -tulpn //no 4444 or 19900 ports | 
    root@c7e314041b14:/# curl http://127.0.0.1:19900/wd/hub | 
    curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 19900: Connection refused